Is there a Higgs-pole like the $Z$-pole?
Why isn’t there studies of direct Higgs production like for the $Z$ boson?
Looking for future colliders, they all aim for
$$e-e+ -> HZ $$
which for me makes sense for measuring a physical Higgs but wouldn’t a run in
$$e-e+ -> H -> fermion-antifermion$$ works in general to study the Higgs mass and couplings?
Since the $Z$-pole is so useful to study the $Z$ boson what’s the reason behind not having something similar with the Higgs? Is it forbidden for some reason I’m missing? It’s suppressed from the $Z$ and photon contributions?

The $e^+ e^- \to H$ vertex will give a factor of the electron Yukawa to the amplitude. But it's ridiculously small, hence, interactions like you suggested are suppressed.

Additionally, it's worth noting though that there is a way to create a Higgs from $e^+e^-$ that's less suppressed, which is vector boson fusion, and as far as I know, it will be investigated in the FCCee, it's just less dominant than Higgstrahlung at the energy ranges of the FCCee if Im not mistaken.

Thanks for your comments. Indeed, it seems that the only reason is the suppression due to the e-H couplings. Apparently, there are studies (link) for the s-channel Higgs production for the muon collider given that in that case the couplings are much much higher. Even in that case the Higgs pole peak it's soft and spread.
